# Proposed changes “suggested” by moderators have a display bug

Tags: bug, documentation, proposed-changes

A moderator deleted a topic, and the edit summary shows this:

[image: STATUS: Approved by]

It should either say:

> STATUS: ***Trusted to make this change without review***

or:

> STATUS: **Approved by [animuson ♦](https://stackoverflow.com/users/246246/animuson)**
>   ***Trusted to make this change without review***

Comment: Noticed this when I made my first change. It was weird.